# How To Find Any Value in Fire store

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I Have the same key `M6LMD0D7oyW1ueNKU2c6sXcZZFd2` I just want to check if this is present or not in Firestore. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a simple `get()` query. For a more complex retrieval of a document like listening to live updates and performing filter operations please refer to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#kotlin+ktx_2).

```
val docRef = db.collection("users").document(user.userId) // Access userId    

docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a particular user (document) exists in a collection in Firestore, you can simply use a `get()` call and attach a complete listener. In code, it will be as simple as:

```
val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid
val uidRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("users").document(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val document = task.result
        if (document.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"The user already exists.")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "The user doesn't exist.")
        }
    } else {
        task.exception?.message?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, it)  //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Hanif. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?